# Matthew 20:16 Badges

Tags: discussion, badges

I think it would be appropriate on this site to add a new set of badges, based on [Matthew 20:16](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2020:16&version=NIV).  I propose the following badges be awarded for the following criteria:

- **Deacon** 100 accumulated down votes on answers
- **Elder** 100 accumulated down votes on questions with 50% or more being closed
- **Apostle** Achieves negative reputation

Comment: You want to *encourage* bad behaviour?!

Comment: I don't think you can get *"negative reputation"*. 1 is the minimum.

Comment: ...So hoping for this to happen, you made a post that's sure to get a few downvotes? :P

Comment: **<sigh>** Does nobody have a sense of humor?

Comment: @Wikis That would just lend support to the view that the apostolic age is over.

Answer (score 5):

I think these are terrible badges.

- We shouldn't encourage people to generated downvotable content
- We don't want to make our mods' jobs harder in the future by encouraging closeable content.
- The lowest you can go rep-wise is 1 so Apostle is impossible.

If we are going to suggest badges with these titles then perhaps the following would be more appropriate:

- Deacon - Edits, comments and upvotes new users (drawing on the service part of the Deaconate)
- Elder - 3 years service 10k rep
- Apostle - Private Beta member with 10k or higher rep

Comment: Although it's not _technically_ impossible (like negative reputation) for a private beta member to get 10k or higher rep, it's almost impossible, given the daily 200 rep limit for most things.

Comment: @Flimzy I'm not saying during the beta. I'm just saying a user who was active during private beta. Kind of an original high rep member

Comment: Ah... okay... interesting idea.  I think it still completely misses the intent of Matthew 20:16... and the intended humor of the original suggestion. :)

Comment: I thought of posting a not very serious proposal for *lead* badges for negative "accomplishments". Even as explicitly negative awards, such might encourage people to earn such. (Perhaps 'uranium' would be the negative equivalent of 'gold'; perhaps 'rust' for 'bronze' :-/ )