# Shouldn't the user list be sorted ascending, based on Luke 13:30?

Tags: discussion, voting, irony, users

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Matthew 20:16 Badges](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236/matthew-2016-badges)

> And, behold, there are last which shall be first, and there are first which shall be last.
>
> Luke 13:30

In addition, a user could have the possibility to downvote himselfe, as an example of humility.

Comment: We suggested badges to this effect early on. The irony went over like a lump of coal in a Christmas stocking -- apparently nobody was in a humorous mood that day.

Comment: Here is the earlier [attempt at badges](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/236/matthew-2016-badges) mentioned by Caleb. (I'm sure it'll get even more down votes now that I'm pointing it out again.)